# Ubuntu Touch; How do I import .vcf contacts?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, contacts

I have just got Ubuntu Touch up and running on my phone (Nexus 4) and am enjoying it! I have got my photos and music onto it, but I cannot find how to import my .vcf contacts file. I have read all the articles I can find on the subject and they only have instructions for importing contacts from Google, but that is useless for me. I have searched askubuntu to no avail.

Comment: You didn't search well. Just searching by tag `contacts` gives you this question: [Ubuntu Touch (officially launched version): How to sync contacts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360466/ubuntu-touch-officially-launched-version-how-to-sync-contacts)

Comment: I didn't know about using tags to search! Thank you for telling me about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu Touch has EDS (Evolution-data-server) installed. So you can sync it using syncevolution.

First install latest stable version from repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository deb http://downloads.syncevolution.org/apt stable main
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install syncevolution-evolution
```

If you are using Google-Contacts, then export all contacts as vcf (i.e allcontacts.vcf) & then import it using following command at terminal (Change the path & database accordingly):

```
syncevolution --import /path/to/file/allcontacts.vcf backend=evolution-contacts database=Personal
```

To know the names of all available databases type:

```
syncevolution --print-databases
```

For more info visit:

- [SyncEvolution - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution)
- [SyncEvolution](https://syncevolution.org/)