# How can I import an address book in Ubuntu-for-devices?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have installed Ubuntu for devices (devel channel, version 243) on my Nexus 4.

When I go the the "contacts" application it notices that I haven't got any contacts and asks "Could you like to sync contacts from online accounts now?". Unfortunately I see nothing to select to indicate "yes" or any means of selecting online accounts. Swiping up also does not reveal anything. How can I import my contacts?

Comment: Here you can find a good answer:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/425315/ubuntu-touch-how-do-i-import-vcf-contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing using the answer from Ralph indeed worked. Thanks. You do need to make sure that you have no contacts without phone number (I had a couple of these in the address book I imported from Google).