# How can contacts and calendars be synchronised?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, calendar, contacts, ms-exchange

In all the articles and reviews about Ubuntu Phone, I have been missing one crucial information: What protocols are supported to synchronise your contacts and calendars with your device? CalDav/GroupDav? ActiveSync? Gmail?

Comment: Yes caldav/carddav is supported as they use `evolution-data-server` as backend. You can use Syncevolution to sync local evolution database with any caldav/carddav server including Google. Link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360466/ & http://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to sync your Official Aquaris Ubuntu Edition with e.g. Owncloud using CardDAV. This is what I did (see [wiki.ubuntuusers.de](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Evolution/Synchronisation) for source):

1. First I added the certificate of my site to the folder /usr/share/ca-certificates and updates the ca-cert database, since it is self-signed:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/loop0 / -o remount,rw
   sudo cp /home/phablet/Downloads/server.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates
   ```

   Add a star to the new certificate while running the configuration

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
   ```
2. Add the syncevolution configuration:

   ```
   syncevolution --keyring=no --configure --template webdav username=<USERNAME> password=<PASSWORD> syncurl="in-its.de/owncloud" target-config@owncloud
   syncevolution --configure --template SyncEvolution_Client sync=none syncURL=local://@owncloud username= password= peerIsClient=1 owncloud
   syncevolution --configure database=https://<SERVER>/owncloud/remote.php/carddav/addressbooks/<USERNAME>/contacts backend=carddav target-config@owncloud contacts
   syncevolution --configure sync=two-way backend=contacts database="Persönlich" owncloud contacts
   ```
3. Run sync:

   ```
   syncevolution --sync slow owncloud contacts
   ```

That made all my Owncloud contacts available on my Ubuntu Phone.

And CalDAV works similar:

```
syncevolution --configure database=https://<SERVER>/owncloud/remote.php/caldav/calendars/<USERNAME>/personal backend=caldav target-config@owncloud calendar
syncevolution --configure sync=two-way backend=events database="Persönlich" owncloud calendar
```

And then sync it:

```
syncevolution --sync slow owncloud calendar
```

So CalDAV and CardDAV are working!

Comment: So you have to manually run those commands from time to time?

Comment: I guess you could add the script to your cron (e.g. /etc/cron.hourly), but I didn't try it.

Comment: @user1039462 The only command you need to run is `syncevolution --sync  owncloud calendar`. The other commands are for configuration & once the configuration was done, it is saved in the system.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to connect to my phone by updating the repositories with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools && sudo apt-get update
```

But no after setting everything up I get an error when running the sync

```
[ERROR @baikal] transport problem: PROPFIND: Neon error code 1, no HTTP status: Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted
```

So I guess I need some kind of certificate for my baikal server. Any idea how to fix this?

I installed owncloud on my NAS! Now everything works! Thanks for the instructions!
But is the phone now keeping the contacts synced?

Answer (score 0):

Not true at the moment...only can sync contacts and calendar from google. There is no way to setup other CalDav/CardDav or ActiveSync accounts via the Settings in Ubuntu Touch. If your online info doesn't reside with google services then your out of luck.