# Syncevolution in cronjob to sync the ubuntu phone via caldav/arddav

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, calendar, contacts

I want to sync my contacts and calendar from my Ubuntu Phone to a self-hosted owncloud server. Since there is no out-of-the-box support yet, I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/600629/399891) explaination. However, this only works from within the terminal on the ubuntu phone. If I try

```
syncevolution --sync slow owncloud calendar
```

over adb or from a cronjob, I get

```
creating source registry: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've understood that "syncevolution --sync slow owncloud calendar" should be use only for the first sync.

After that you should use :

```
syncevolution owncloud calendar
```

To do a cron job, I've got the same issue. One solution which work for me is :

**Method 1 :**

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=Yourdbussessioadress && /usr/bin/syncevolution owncloud calendar
```

To get Yourdbussessioadress  :

```
echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

**Method 2 :** 
I put these commands in an syncevolution.sh script like that :

```
#!/bin/sh
# Synchronisation des calendriers syncevolution
export DISPLAY=:0.0 
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=Yourdbussessioadress 
syncevolution owncloud calendar

exit 0
```

I've placed this script in /home/phablet/bin, make it executable and do this in crontab -e

```
@daily sh /home/phablet/bin/synccalendar.sh
```

I'm still stuck on one thing. The $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS value is changing at reboot of ubuntu. I've got an other script on internet (using the command sed) to put the good value of $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in the syncevolution.sh script. I've put this script in /etc/rc.local to do the job on reboot of ubuntu. But it doesn't work for me (Its like $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is empty just after reboot)

If someone could help more.

**UPDATE 22/04/15 :**

Replace "export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=Yourdbussessioadress" by theses commands :

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(ps -u phablet e | grep -Eo 'dbus-daemon.*address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-[A-Za-z0-9]{10}' | tail -c35)
```

It works like a charm for me (tested with Method 2 using a sh script where "phablet" is the default user of ubuntu touch). Thanks to a KDE forum where I've found theses commands lines.

*(Next steps :*

1. *Find a way to do a backup of photos on personal server with rsync using ssh and why not after a backup of SMS&MMS, some configurations files, ...*
2. *Mount an sftp server on ubuntu touch)*

Comment: Thank you very much !!! On my device it works like a charm too! :-)