# syncevolution d-bus error syncing ubuntu phone via carddav

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, owncloud-server

To sync the contacts of my ubuntu-phone witch my ownCloud server I set up a syncevolution configuration and started 1st time syncing:

```
syncevolution --sync slow owncloud contacts
```

As a result I get this error:

```
creating source registry: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

and then followed the instructions described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611761/syncevolution-in-cronjob-to-sync-the-ubuntu-phone-via-caldav-arddav/611961#611961?newreg=fb1d6959cc1347618eb9c257afd83d45), but then I get as a next error:

```
creating source registry: Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" (No such file or directory)
```

.. could not find any help on this issue so far, can anyone give me some help please?

Answer (score 0):

Folks, finally I managed to solve the issue. The X11 error is issued because I used the syncevolution commands with "sudo". Also I cleaned up all the /home/phablet/.cache/syncevolution/* files, and removed the /home/phablet/.config/syncevolution directory. Reconfigured syncevolution (NOT using sudo) and then everything worked :)